# Typescript not able to deduct generic type from argument

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm writing a generic React List builder.

I have a type describing an API route which take Result as generic argument.
I haveroute descriptions for each of my API routes. I want to create a function returning a React functional component with parameterized behaviors.

The "framework" part:

```
export interface RouteDescription<Result> {
}

interface GenericResponse<Entity> {
    data: Entity[];
}
```

My route description:

```
interface MyEntity {
    id: number;
}

interface MyResult {
    data: MyEntity[];
}

const myRouteDescription: RouteDescription<MyResult> = {
};
```

My React component & List factory :

```
function Component<Entity>(a: Entity) {
}

function useList<Entity, R extends GenericResponse<Entity>>(
    route: RouteDescription<R>,) {
    return Component<Entity>;
}

const component = useList(myRouteDescription);
```

Typescript compiler is not able to detect Entity type from the route description :
[image: parameter is unknown]

I expect to have MyEntity instead of unknwon.

Is what I expect feasible with Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript struggles inferring nested generics. In your example the generic argument `Entity` in `R extends GenericResponse<Entity>` can't be inferred. I believe this has to do with [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213). As a workaround you could extract that type using [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) like so:

```
export interface RouteDescription<Result> {}

interface GenericResponse<Entity> {
  data: Entity[];
}

interface MyEntity {
  id: number;
}

interface MyResult {
  data: MyEntity[];
}

declare const myRouteDescription: RouteDescription<MyResult>;

function Component<Entity>(a: Entity) {}

function useList<R extends GenericResponse<unknown>>(
  route: RouteDescription<R>,
) {
  return Component<R["data"][number]>;
}

const component = useList(myRouteDescription);
//    ^? const component: (a: MyEntity) => void
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgJQgFdUARYAZ2ygTBgQiQB59KiAbGAPjgG8BfAFCDkqDDjwBxYEjQJsrCpCQVgTAKIoEMAJ49eguHAAmmGJgBccTfV0BtALoBuQUJEo0WXHACyOm9o6fIaIxlZIRAC2AEZoLm6inhK%20Oooc8AZGpuZWfgH2zq7CxsDY7JhQeNiMFPCRqcRklNS09IxWhCTA5FQ0dAzMfmmcXC6C6ERI2G1IcADCEJHKMjAaWrpcABSW1us6AJR8bhNTM3BEqgAyCLUscKCoSMYUcNKyNAqUyqpMkwDWSAgAHckFwtiEoI1gB0oT0Wv1GCwuAAaQSHTJwSowIhQWYLJaMFYsOwAImymBJDjsERiaAcoyKgmqKng1QJshQcAAvOcrjcYJt6p0mr1WgN9i4APSSoxGAB6AH44MzasrFssUFZtrl-HtDlyeAA3CAIYyCIA)